# why error-page in web.xml cannot capture exceptions thrown from struts2 prepare method

Tags: exception, struts2, web.xml

i declare a global exception handler in web.xml

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
<location>/exceptionHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

it works fine most of the time. But it cannot capture the exceptions thrown from the prepare method in struts2 actions

anyone know why

Answer (score 1):

Probably because Struts2's `ExceptionMappingInterceptor` catches exceptions and maps them to error pages itself.

You can use the following in your struts.xml:

```
<global-results>
    <result name="error">/WEB-INF/error.jsp</result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"/>
</global-exception-mappings>
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `ExceptionMappingInterceptor` from the interceptor stack if you really want to use the web.xml method.

Comment: however, this only happens in prepare method. if ExceptionMappingInterceptor catches exceptions, it will catches all. but the servlet exception handler in my web.xml can capture the exceptions from the actions.

Comment: Are you sure this happens in all prepare methods or just a certain one? The PrepareInterceptor just re-throws any exception encountered while executing prepare. Perhaps you should post the code for the prepare method you're having trouble with.

Comment: all prepare methods. in those prepare methods, only contain methods accessing database via hibernate. Now i just forward all the exceptions captured by struts2 to the exception handler in web.xml. Wired!